# Find some integral with Lebesgue measure and counting measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If we define D as:
$$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|0<x=y<1\}$$
and let m be the Lebesgue-measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and the counting measure $\tau$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.
Then I have to find:
$$\int\int1_{D}(x,y)dm(x)d \tau(y)$$
and
$$\int\int1_{D}(x,y)d \tau(y)dm(x)$$
I think that
$$\int\int1_{D}(x,y)dm(x)d \tau(y)=0$$
bacause the inner integral must give 0 while we have the lebesgue measue on the integral?

While the other integral must give:
$$\int\int1_{D}(x,y)d \tau(y)dm(x)=1$$
while the inner integral must give 1

But I'm not sure if it correct and how I proof these results? Can someone help me to show it correctly and not only by these intuitive thoughts?

Comment: What you have done is correct. What makes you confused?

Comment: Nice, that my thoughts are correct, but I’m not sure how to prove these results? How will you write it up formally?

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $x$ we have $\int 1_D(x,y)d\tau (y) = 1$ because $1_D(x,y)=1$ if $y=x$ and $0$ otherwise. [You are integrating the characteristic function of the set $\{x\}$ and the integral of the characteristic function of any set $E$ is $\tau (E)$].

On the other hand, for fixed $y$,  $\int 1_D(x,y)dm(x) = 0$ because you are integrating the characteristic function of $\{y\}$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure and this function is $0$ almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Hi Kavi, I also have to conclude that $\tau$ not can be sum-finite. Can you help me with that?